# How to insert lines of text after any C function begin and before end of function?

Tags: c, regex, grep

I have hundred of C-functions like

```
void test()
{
    <content of function>
}
```

(Functions may have a return value `UBYTE`, `BOOL`, `WORD`, ...)

Now I would like to add a text to all functions as follows:

```
void test()
{
    LABEEL_BEGIN
    <blank line>
    <content of function>
    <blank line>
    LABEL_END
}
```

So  I need to insert `LABEL_BEGIN` and a blank line at the start of the function and a blank line and `LABEL_END` at end of the function.

I assume that this might be possible with some ticky regex!? Or is there a Text Editor available which has such a feature? Currently, I have MS Studio 2013 IDE, Notapad++, Textpad, PSpad available and also the GNU grep 2.4.5 command line tool.

Comment: If you bothered to format your code, the opening and closing braces might be a good bet to use in a search & replace type situation

Comment: @ChrisTurner Unless there are compound statements inside the function, which seems kind of likely.

Comment: @Lundin but only the function levels start with no spaces/tabs before them :)

Comment: If you are okay with putting in a bit of effort, clang's [LibTooling](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibTooling.html) is a very nice option.

Answer (score 0):

The following regex will select the each void, its name, any parameters and its first opening curly brace. If you match this against your input, you can take it's match index and match length to find the beginning index of the void's inner content. You can then add you're additional content at the index.

```
(void [\w_][\w\d_]*\(.*\)(\r|)(\n|){)
```

Feel free to play around with it here: https://regexr.com/3jarc

To get the end of the function, you could use the regex above as a positive lookbehind then match the closing '}'.

Answer (score 0):

What about a brace counter ?

you open your source code file, and you read char by char.
Each time you have '{', you increment the brace_counter, and each time you have '}', you decremente it.

If you found a '{' and the counter is 0 before incrementation, you have the beginning of your function.
If you found a '}' and the counteur is 0 after decrementation, you have the end of your function.

Could this work ? Or there are tricky C syntax that can broke that down ?

Comment: That'd also match structs (for example)

Comment: Ah, that's rigth, i forgot that (and enum, and union, etc etc).
So, maybe, have a buffer that retain the "line" that is just before the first '{' and parse it to know if this is a function. (I know it's not juste the previous "line", because it can be on multiple line, but that's the idea).
Or more simplier : You modify the source code with the bracket counter, and after you fix the bad struct/enum/union (must give critical error).
If there is hundred function, there probably shouldn't be many struct/enum/union in a .c